# Pages dont slide to next page when using ion-slide

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, segment

Im currently trying to slide between two ion-segments with slides. Here is the code I tried: I wrapped the slides keyword around the lists. Atm when I run it, I see a slide animation but its not navigating to the next page. Do I have to write some additional nav. stuff? Ive added the code now in a stackblitz.

[SegmentApp](http://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tdfbd4)